# How to add a column having Bond's last coupon payment date in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe, quantitative-finance

Assume today's date is 01-11-2013 and the bond's coupon rate is annual.

```
df["Last Coupon"]=df["Maturity"] - (datetime.timedelta(days=365)*df["Benchmark"])
```

The output from the above code is:

```
"Benchmark"  "Maturity"  "Last Coupon Date"

  1     20-10-2014  20-10-2013

  2     15-07-2015  15-07-2013

  3     15-09-2016  **16**-09-2013

  4     15-09-2017  **16**-09-2013

  9     20-04-2022  **22**-04-2013

 10     20-10-2023  **22**-10-2013
```

The ***desired output*** for "Last Coupon Date":

```
"Benchmark"  "Maturity"  "Last Coupon Date"

  1     20-10-2014  20-10-2013

  2     15-07-2015  15-07-2013

  3     15-09-2016  15-09-2013

  4     15-09-2017  15-09-2013

  9     20-04-2022  20-04-2013

  10    20-10-2023  20-10-2013
```

How to get the desired output?

Comment: Please post the sample input dataframe for which you've posted the desired output.

Comment: The original dataframe (df) has two columns "Benchmark" and "Maturity". The bond gives out coupon annually. And today's date is 01/1//2013

Comment: Please post the original df in question itself. It would make it easier to understand.

Comment: This is the original dataset(df). Everything is there. Nothing else is required

Answer (score 1):

Subtracting 365 days, will cause deflections if a leap year comes in the range.

```
df['Last_Coupon_Date'] = df['Maturity'] -(pd.DateOffset(years=1)*df['Benchmark'])
```

This might generate some warnings. If your dataset is not very big, you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks Rishabh. Got the desired output.